# BabylonJs bones demo not working correctly on iPad and iPhone

Tags: babylonjs

I've selected babylon js to integrate a 3D human model to one of my mobile application developments. I'm using Ionic framework to write hybrid applications for iPad and android tablets. But when I integrated the 3D model in iPad, the animation was not working as expected.

In order to find the issue, I tested the Bones example in babylon js example list on browser and experienced that even that example doesn't work on the safari browser of the iPad and iPhone.

Here are some visual  outputs of what I tested.

[Example on Mac, Chrome](https://streamable.com/x6p3d) : Successfully working

[Example on iPad, Safari](https://streamable.com/2lq7o) : Issues in human 3D model

[Example on iPad, Chome](https://streamable.com/whnoa) : Issues in human 3D model

[Example on Android, Chrome](https://streamable.com/d01qi) : Successfully working

In summary, the 3D human model has few issues in iPad. I've experienced same issues in iPhone too.

Can someone help me to understand what would be the problem and any fixes if this is an already known problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is because the number of uniform we can send to iOS WebGL implementation is pretty limited.

You can set mesh.computeBonesUsingShaders = false on iOS to fix the issue